# mongodb .find() does not filter records

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

In the code bellow `Products.find({ "name": search })` does not filter results, instead the whole `MongoDB list` of results is returned.

```
 router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
        const search = req.query.third;
        Products.find({ "name": search }).then(result => {  
            res.render('search', { Products: result });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the value yourself? Also await is not necessary here as you are already using `then catch` form.

Comment: `find` returns an array of all matching documents. `findOne` returns just one matching document.